# How to show Radio Button Checked in Radio Group when value get from Web Service?

Tags: android, web-services, radio-button, radio-group

I have five BadioButton in RadioGroup. Now what I want that if I receive "NDS" from Web Service then its show "NDS" RadioButton Checked or if I receive "DS" then its show "DS" checked. how can I achieve this?

Below is my Radio Group XML Code:

```
<RadioGroup android:id="@+id/rdoCnsumerCatgory"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <RadioButton android:id="@+id/rdoDS"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="DS"
                android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
                android:textColor="#000000"
                android:textSize="10sp"
                android:textStyle="bold" />

            <RadioButton android:id="@+id/rdoNDS"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="NDS"
                android:textColor="#000000"
                android:textSize="10sp"
                android:textStyle="bold" />

            <RadioButton android:id="@+id/rdoSip"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="SIP"
                android:textColor="#000000"
                android:textSize="10sp"
                android:textStyle="bold" />

            <RadioButton android:id="@+id/rdoMip"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
                android:text="MIP"
                android:textColor="#000000"
                android:textSize="10sp"
                android:textStyle="bold" />

            <RadioButton android:id="@+id/rdoMl"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="ML"
                android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
                android:textColor="#000000"
                android:textSize="10sp"
                android:textStyle="bold" />
        </RadioGroup>
```

Comment: try if else conition or switch condition

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Try This**

> **By if-else method**

```
  String mValue="";


        RadioButton rdoMl,rdoMip,rdoSip,rdoNDS,rdoDS;
        if(mValue.equalsIgnoreCase("NDS"))
        {
            rdoNDS.setChecked(true);
        }
        else if(mValue.equalsIgnoreCase("DS"))
        {
            rdoDS.setChecked(true);
        }
        else if(mValue.equalsIgnoreCase("MIP"))
        {
            rdoMip.setChecked(true);
        }
        else if(mValue.equalsIgnoreCase("SIP"))
        {
            rdoSip.setChecked(true);
        }
        else if(mValue.equalsIgnoreCase("ML"))
        {
            rdoMl.setChecked(true);
        }
```

> **By switch method**

```
        switch(mValue) {
            case "NDS":
                rdoNDS.setChecked(true);
                break;
            case "DS":
                rdoDS.setChecked(true);
                break;
            case "MIP":
                rdoMip.setChecked(true);
                break;
            case "SIP":
                rdoSip.setChecked(true);
                break;
            case "ML":
                rdoMl.setChecked(true);
                break;

            // etc...
        }
```